# Need to set an App Image as executable on my Chromebook

Tags: linux, chromebook, appimage

Basically Im Looking to make an AppImage executable to install a music tool called LMMS on my **Chromebook** but the commands that I see people use in their terminal, do not work in **crosh**. I.e. "sudo" , "chmod"

What commands could I even use to install this tool

Answer (score 2):

I've created an application to install Appimage applications. My application name is Happim. (Happim stands for Handle Appimage)

Though I haven't tested in a Chromebook, it should work fine as ChromeOS is also a Linux distro. [Please go through this link before installing the prerequisites:](https://github.com/suramuthurs/Happim?tab=readme-ov-file#2-troubles-in-installing-prerequisites-and-solution1)

After installing Happim, what all you need to do is to

1. Launch Happim by click the icon,
2. Type your Appimage application name.
3. Select your preferred icon and Appimage file through GUI,
4. Click install.

Now, your favorite Appimage's icon will be available among your installed programs. You can add to favorites by right-clicking and selecting 'Add to favorites'.

Free to use. Available in github.

Ensure the necessary packages have been installed.

```
git clone https://github.com/suramuthurs/Happim.git
cd Happim
python3 install.py
```

Go through my readme.md in github for the solution in case it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Crosh is a restricted terminal mostly for debugging and diagnostics.  To launch your own apps you need either Crouton (older Chromebooks) or Crostini (linux VM on newer models).

I'll assume you're on an older model since if you had Crostini you'd probably know.  A guide for installing Crouton is here: https://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/